# How can I hide empty Quick Tab item when there is no content in it?

Tags: blocks

I don't want to show quicktab item when there is no content in it.
But I can see empty divs in it.

```
 <div class="view-content">
      <div class="item-list"> 
        <ul>    
      <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
              <!-- NOTHING IS HERE SO DO NOT DISPLAY -->   
      </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
```

How Can I remove the quick tab for above empty content.

Answer (score 1):

I already checked it. But still the 'View' I assigned to that quicktab renders some div's which I posted in my question. By the way, I found the solution, you just need to add the filter in that particular view. Suppose view of content type 'movies' then add a filter "content:movies => not empty (IS NOT NULL)". That's it.  Hope this help others too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Quick tabs (admin/structure/quicktabs) and edit your instance, and check Hide empty tabs option. Then Empty tabs will not be displayed.

[image]

Comment: I already checked it. But still the 'View' I assigned to that quicktab renders some div's which I posted in my question. By the way, I found the solution, you just need to add the filter in that particular view. Suppose view of content type 'movies' then add a filter "content:movies => IS NOT NULL". That's it.  Hope this help others too.